# reusing logging config across python modules

Tags: python-2.7, logging

This snippet creates a logging filter that puts ERROR level and above into the console and DEBUG and above into the log file.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to  reuse that config across my various modules so that I'm writing to the same logfile, but the **name**  correctly indicates the module that generated the message.

Thanks in advance!

```
import logging


default_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("error.log", "a")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

noralog = logging.getLogger(__name__)
noralog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
noralog.addHandler(console_handler)
noralog.addHandler(file_handler)

noralog.debug('PUT ME ONLY IN THE FILE')
noralog.error('STREAM AND FILE')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the best solution:
    #noralog.py
    def setup_logging(localname):
        import logging

```
    default_formatter = logging.Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("error.log", "a")
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

    noralog = logging.getLogger(localname)
    noralog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    noralog.addHandler(console_handler)
    noralog.addHandler(file_handler)
    return noralog


#othermod.py
import noralog

ff = noralog.setup_logging(__name__)
ff.debug('PUT THIS ONLY IN FILE LOG')
ff.error('PUT THIS IN STREAM AND FILE LOG')
```